# JS - How to put a local variable right

Tags: javascript

I have a JS module and I want to set a value for a local variable. I thought I can use the same names using "this" :

JS

```
(function() {
    var amount = 0;
    var setAmount = function(amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
  ........
})();
```

Comment: Learn how `this` works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amount` is in the scope of the function, so you don't need a `this` key word.

```
(function(){

 var amount = 0;

 var setAmount = function( newAmount ){
   amount = newAmount;
 }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var amount = 0, setAmount = function(myAmount) {
 myAmount = amount;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using self execution anonymous function you haven't "this", because this isn't an object. In your case you just put:

```
(function(){

 var amount = 0;

 var setAmount = function( pamount ){

                     amount = pamount;
                }
  ........
 })();
```

Comment: change the variable name of the `amount` parameter

Comment: This happens becuase you have in same execution context two variables with same name.

Answer (score 0):

this is how `this` works

```
var x = {
amount : 0,
setAmount : function(){
    alert(this.amount);
  }
}

x.setAmount(); //alert 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two boxes, one is large and one is small.  The small box is inside the larger box.

The small box represents the `setAmount` function you defined.  The large box represents the closure that wraps that setAmount function.

Each box only knows what is inside itself and what is inside of its parent outer boxes.

The keyword `this`, means *inside this box*.

The small box can already see `amount` because it is in the larger box.  If you define `this.amount = something` inside the small box, it's essentially the same thing as saying `var amount = something`.

You also need to be careful with argument names because that could only lead to a headache if you're not careful.

The issue you're running into is a scoping problem, if you absolutely have to name your variables this way - here is a solution.

```
(function() {
    var amount = 0;
    var scope = this;
    var setAmount = function(amount) {
        scope.amount = amount;
    }
  ........
})();
```

What this does is create a variable in the larger box that refers back to its scope (in our example back to its own box).  Because the small box is inside the large box, it can see the scope variable.